# Getting A Type-Specific Response From A WCF REST Generic Request?

Tags: c#, json, generics, serialization

I am designing a WCF REST service. A requirement for the design is that the 
client is unaware of the particulars of a given request. For example, the
following request:

https://www.domain.com/dashboard/group/id/0

Would return:

```
Request: GetGroup(GroupId = 0)
Response: 
{
Title="Country",
children = 
{
title="USA", Id=1, type=GROUP},
{title="England", Id=2, type=GROUP}
}
}
```

And the following request:

https://www.domain.com/dashboard/group/id/3

Would return:

```
Request: GetGroup(groupId = 3)
Response: 
{
Title="Customers",
children = 
{
title="General Motors", Id=1, type=CUSTOMER},
{title="General Electric", Id=2, type=CUSTOMER}
}
}
```

**MY QUESTION IS** how do I take a generic REST request and return a type-specific response?

In my project, there are a few Types that will be serialized in the JSON response. The serialized object depends on the passed-in groupId parameter. They are:

```
GROUP
CUSTOMER
FACILITY
TANK
```

In a related post, it was suggested that I create a base class that exposes GetGroupById
and the above classes should override the base class method. If this sounds like a good 
example of how to attack this problem, I'd appreciate an example. Or, alternatively, other suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a service that returns a Stream and use the `JsonSerializer` to serialize your objects into a `MemoryStream`, and then return the `MemoryStream` from the service:

```
public Stream GetSomeObject(int groupId)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    switch(groupId)
    {
        case 2:
            var groups = GetGroups(); // fill the groups however
            bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(groups));
            break;
        case 3:
            var customers = GetCustomers();
            bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializer.Serialize(customers));
            break;
    }

    return new MemoryStream(bytes);
}
```

In that case, you would simply load the appropriate object into memory based on the parameters and return the appropriate strongly typed object via the `Stream`.

This is the same approach I've used in the past to return Json results from a WCF Service without the type information (the approach was suggested by a member Microsoft's WCF team, so I figured it was fairly reliable).

Comment: Thanks Justin - this sounds closer to what I was looking for. Do you know of any examples out there of how to implement your suggestion? Thanks again.

Comment: Justin, for the JsonSerializer method you are referring to in your code, are you using Newtonsoft.Json or some other DLL? Where is it coming from? I am using Framework 4

Comment: @Code Sherpa - Sorry. I mis-typed that bit. I'm using the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Justin, that works. Much appreciated. So, I am further along but am having problems figuring out how to serialize the type-specific objects in memory. I have traditionally converted my domain objects to data transfer objects prior to sending them along the wire but am not sure how to do that with a Stream. I have re-posted my problem here (as it is off topic). If you have a chance to chime in, I'd appreciate it. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898663/system-io-stream-to-data-transfer-object-prior-to-wcf-rest-serialization